# How to continue to resize 3DObject on click in Three.js, is there another method for resizing other than scale.set?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, resize

My first question on StackOverflow!

I am creating a javascript interactive game and I want the mango to become bigger/smaller/different color/etc every time an event happens to it. I'm testing and I've put an event listener on the mango and it resizes, but only once, using scale.set in my callback. Is there another way to do this? I want it to continue to increase in size until a certain, yet undetermined, size. I tried using percentages which just resulted in the same thing plus my linter yelling at me. Here is my relevant code:

```
const Mango = function() {
  this.mesh = new THREE.Object3D();
  const geom = new THREE.BoxGeometry(8, 16, 5, 8, 8, 8);

  // making the box round
  for (let i = 0; i< geom.vertices.length; i++) {
    geom.vertices[i].normalize().multiplyScalar(16);
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < geom.faces.length; i ++) {
    let face = geom.faces[i];

    face.vertexNormals[0].copy( geom.vertices[face.a] ).normalize();
    face.vertexNormals[1].copy( geom.vertices[face.b] ).normalize();
    face.vertexNormals[2].copy( geom.vertices[face.c] ).normalize();
  }

  // making it oblong
  geom.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeScale(1.0, 1.3, 0.6));

  // adding mango skin
  const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
  const mangoMap = loader.load("images/mangoMap.jpg");
  const mat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: 0xffd507,
    shininess: 40,
    map: mangoMap,
  });
  const mango = new THREE.Mesh(geom, mat);

  // adding eventlistener
  const domEvents = new THREEx.DomEvents(camera, renderer.domElement);
  domEvents.addEventListener(mango, 'click', function increaseMangoSize(e) {
     mango.scale.set(1.2, 1.2, 1.2);
  });

  this.mesh.add(mango);

};
```

Also, if you see anything else in my code that you'd like to comment on or helpfully critique, please let me know! I've only just started working with Three.js today and have a lot to learn.

Answer (score 0):

I FIGURED IT OUT!! I used

```
mango.scale.multiplyScalar(1.2);
```

instead and it works. PHEW!

Comment: but please let me know if anyone has any other comments/suggestions!